# Folder appearing as git submodule (grayed out) when there's no git files in the supposed submodule?

Tags: git, github

I had a repo that became a folder of a bigger repo. I deleted the all the git files for it because I do not want it to be a submodule. When I type `git remote -v` its the larger repos remote. Yet, the folder in question appears as a grayed out submodule in Github.

Comment: "it appears as a submodule" -- what are you referring to as "it" here?

Comment: @ThomasStringer The folder appearing as a submodule. I edited the post, thanks.